# Is there a TreeView with colums in Avalonia or some analog of it?

Tags: c#, user-interface, desktop-application, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a desktop app written in WinForms that displays sets of nested data in a TreeView with columns aka TreeList (data is folders and files with columns for sizes and some custom parameters). I am writing new crosplatform app with Avalonia and looking for a way to do the same but all I see is simple TreeView and GridView\DataGrid.

My main goal is to have a way to browse and select nested data in a dialog that returns list of selected data to work with further. But I also need to see some parameters of that data.

Is there a way to implement TreeList or maybe there is some analog to display a tree and data associated with its nodes at the same time?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `TreeDataGrid` that you could be potentially interested in, but the project status for today is defined as "early beta", so it might contain some bugs:

https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia.Controls.TreeDataGrid